# Visual studio 2022 - "compare with unmodified" feature doesn't work anymore with double click

Tags: configuration, visual-studio-2022

Two days ago with a double click on a modified file, in my Git changes window, I could open a side by side compare view, with the unmodified previous version.
Now only a selection from right click can make that happens.
How i could fix this behaviour?
(I didn't modified anything in my configuration)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also face the same issue, searched on google but no help. Then is started exploring VS2022 options and able to fix this.
Go to git changes window and in Changes section click ellipses (...) and click "Compare File As Default Action". Check below image for more
[Git Changes Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GtZ7.png)

Comment: thank you, solve my issoue
I don't know why, but I've thought that i've already tried that.

Answer (score 1):

Open "Git Changes", on "Changes" right corner will see "...", click on them and then choose "Compare File as Default Action".